# VSTO Template UI doesn't appear when 2 seperate dll's are in the project

Tags: c#, user-interface, vsto

I have been trying to get a VSTO template for excel to install but I can't see the VSTO ribbon buttons or task pane when I open the template after the install. At first I didn't think it was installing at all. The project works fine in visual studio.

I followed the article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx & as above the UI elements were not visible. I then followed the same article for a very basic template project & it worked fine.

I removed all the code from the UI of my template project, recreated the install package & it installed & I could see the UI. I uncommented the code till i found the lines which were preventing me from seeing the UI. 
There are 2 seperate Dll's that the template uses, they are both in the references of the template project and they are both showing as being detected dependencies in the install project & they are both placed in the install directory of the template. The problem is the UI doesn't appear if I use the dll's in my templates code. I just have to attempt to create an instance of one of the 2 dll's classes and the UI stops appearing.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not included the following -

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices
```